# Change column style depending of source

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to populate a datagrid with one column as a combobox but I need that when the collection binded to the combobox is empty the column becomes a textbox column. I have defined the columns as below:

Binding binding = new Binding("DataContext.Prices");
binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSurceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(UserControl),1);

```
DataGridComboBoxColumn productPrices = new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
{
   ElementSyle = new Style
   {
        TargetType = typeof(ComboBox),
        Setters =
        {
            new Setter
            {
                Property=ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,
                Value= binding
            }
        }
   },
   EditingElementSyle = new Style
   {
        TargetType = typeof(ComboBox),
        Setters =
        {
            new Setter
            {
                Property=ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,
                Value= binding
            }
        }
   },
   DisplayMemberPath = new Binding("Price");
   SelectedValuePath = new Bindnt("Price");
};

myDataGrid.Columns.Add(productPrices);
myDataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn(){ Header="Name", Binding=new Binding("Name")});
```

And I defined myDataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" />
```

In my viewmodel I create a

```
var products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product 
    {
       Name="Prod 1",
       Price="12.5"
    }
}
var prices = new List<PriceL>
{
    new PriceL
    {
       Price="12.5"
    },
    new PriceL
    {
       Price="10"
    }

}

ICollectionView Products = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(products);
ICollectionView Prices = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(prices);
```

I need that when "Prices" is empty the column become in a textbox I am working with MVVM and I tried with elementStyle but I cannot see any event in Combobox that let me verify it's data source. Could any body help me ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found one way to do that

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource={binding} x:Key="DataGrid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource={binding} x:Key="DataGrid2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ID}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Accepted}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource DataGrid1}" DataContext="{Binding MyTable}" Name="myContent"/}    
</Grid>
```

Y por codigo puede cambiarse el content

myContent.Content = this.FindResource("DataGrid2");

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into behaviors to trigger the needed visual changes such as the [DataStateBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723952%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx)? You may want to put in a boolean property in your VM which detects whether the source is valid or not which the behavior can trigger off of.

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to search about it. But do you know any source of information for working with visual studio ?. I am not working on blend

Comment: Download the trial version and get it running. It will only add code to the Xaml and will not tie you into having to purchase the product. But (IMHO) to truly be a Xaml developer knowing Blend will not hurt your career and if you find it a tool to use, get management to buy it.